# Calling 3rd party web services from inside a ASP.Net webservice without delaying response to the originating client

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

The web application I'm working on receives HTTP POST data from an external system run by another company, which essentially tells us when one of our customers performs a particular action. At present, we log the data, update relevant statuses, and it works nice and quickly.

I now have to integrate this into another system so that these updates are pushed out to other third party businesses via HTTP, directly to their systems. I'm conscious that these external services may suddenly be unavailable due to technical issues, especially as some are run by some businesses on nothing more than DSL lines.

Is it possible, that purely from an ASP.net page, I can asynchronously call the external web service, whilst still returning an OK response to the original service provider without a delay incurred by waiting by the extra call to the other web services?

Our service provider, and my web app, only cares we receive the data. If my app times out, they will send it again after a short period, which we don't want (there are cases where the same status will be sent multiple - but different - times for the same customer, but we don't want erroneous multiples)

The third parties receiving the data want the updates immediately, and the only other way I've thought of is if we run an internal Windows (exe) service, create a TCP connection directly to that from my web app, and the new service accepts the data and disconnects my web application quickly, then sends the data on afterwards, but that seems like more complexity than should be required.

Comment: "run an internal Windows (exe) service, create a TCP connection directly to that from my web app". I wouldn't do that. Just have the web app write the data into some sort of queue (it can be as simple as a database table) and have the service poll the queue at frequent intervals and process the next batch of un-processed tasks. This is a pretty standard architecture for doing things like this. These days I believe there are also libraries which can achieve similar things with the context of a web app - I have heard of Quartz.NET Scheduler for instance, there may be others if you search